# Get unique values of a field and prints its length

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table name `Worker` as shown below and I wanted to write an SQL query that fetches the unique values of `DEPARTMENT` from `Worker` table and prints its length. So I tried running this : (Database- Mysql)

Table Name: `Worker`

| worker_id | first_name | last_name | department |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

```sql
select length(distinct(department)) from worker;
```

But it is giving an error saying:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'distinct(department)) from worker' at line 1

But when I ran below query, it works perfectly fine:

```sql
select distinct(length(department)) from worker;
```

Can somebody please explain to me why interchanging distinct and length functions makes query work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The two queries (when syntactically correct) will produce a different result (at least in some cases),  Please add some sample data and the desried output to your question.

Comment: Let say, that you have the following departments `AB`, `CD`, and `XYZ`. What outcome you expect?

Comment: I think you're looking for : SELECT DEPARTMENT, MAX(LENGTH(DEPARTMENT)) FROM WORKER GROUP BY DEPARTMENT

Answer (score 2):

Try not to use distinct like function but clause otherwise it will give syntax error.

Below sql statement will execute as shown below:

```
select distinct (length('xyz'))  ---- length('xyz') : 3
select distinct (3)  ---- output : 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Distinct is not properly a function but a clause

```
 select  distinct length(department) from worker;
```

Anyway in MySQL work also with function syntax

```
  select  distinct( length(department)) from worker;
```

The code with the exchanged token don't work because DISTINCT produce an aggregated result removing the duplicated  values,this implies  that the outer length() function work on not correct set of rows or better the db engine see that there an improper use of the DISTINCT clause and raise the syntax error

```
select length( distinct 'A'  )  this raise an error
```

If you want use the outer length() function you should code this way

```
select length(my_col) from (
 select distinct department  my_col from worker
) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

correct answer :

```sql
select distinct <column_dept> as department,(len(<column_dept>) as length_column_dept from xyz_table
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**In SQL, `Length()` function expects a string expression.
If we pass a keyword or clause such as `DISTINCT(COL_NAME)`, as an argument to the `Length()` function you'll get a syntax error because it's not a valid string expression.**

```
SELECT DISTINCT(LENGTH('stackoverflow')) FROM worker;
```

So, the query first selects the **Worker** table as the source of data, then evaluates the **DISTINCT** keyword to eliminate duplicate values, and then calculates the **length** of each DEPARTMENT value using the LENGTH() function. Finally, the resulting distinct length values are returned in the result.

Answer (score -1):

```
select  distinct( length(department)),department from worker group by department;
```

Comment: [Please do not post an answer that consists essentially of
code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.

Answer (score -2):

select distinct (Department) as 'Unique department', len(Department) as 'length of name' from Worker;